# SDL2 Loading screen/thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, sdl

Hi fellow programmers,

After spending hours on end trying to achieve a loading screen in SDL2, we failed to do so. We're creating a simple 2D open-world survival game (top-down), which requires us to load a lot of tilesets/sprites for different entities (Rabbit, Trees, Rocks etc.)

At first we had only one tileset, containing the trees and the background tiles. Now, however, the map expanded from a 'sample' 50x50 tile-map, to a 1500x1500 tile-map. Result: the game seemed to freeze, but it was loading the tiles/images instead.

Our solution: create a loading screen where we can show the progress of what's currently being loaded. Since our game uses the state-pattern for gamestates (or somewhat like it), we'd have a PlayState and a LoadingState.

We decided to use a regular std::thread to load in all the data required and to convert them to textures. What the thread exactly does, is this:

1. Read a JSON file, containing the data for our map
2. Process the retrieved data and create tilesets from it
3. Load images and create textures

It all works without a thread (except for the 'freeze', which just loads all the above), but with a thread, it's like 60%/40% regarding success/failure. After hours and hours of searching, we found the reason: [SDL2 cannot call](https://wiki.libsdl.org/CategoryRender) SDL_CreateTexture from a different thread other then the main thread.

Right now, we are clueless, since we have no idea on how to show a loading screen, doing all the above actions, without creating a different thread to execute those actions. Therefore our question: is there any way a loading screen can be achieved, the way we've described it above?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not to be polemic but.. if you spent hours trying to create a splash screen and failed, and you're planning to write a 2D open-world survival game.. I'd read some tutorials again.

Comment: https://bugzilla.libsdl.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1995

Comment: @MarcoA. I might have been a little bit exaggerating, but the game itself works (running the game). We've created chunks and such to handle processing of entities. The stupid thing is, creating a simple splash screen and showing the percentage loaded is/seems harder than it is. In other words: our game is up and running, our loading screen isn't.

Comment: @2501 I've read that page, but couldn't exactly determine a definitive solution to the issue (that's why I tried SO).

Answer (score 1):

1. Call IMG_LoadTexture() in a loop on your files until it is the time to display the current frame.
2. Render a simple image displaying the progress.
3. If there are any more textures to load, goto 1

This is done in the same thread.

Comment: Could you explain this a bit more in detail (specifically step 1)?

Comment: @PimVerlangen How are you creating textures?

Comment: `SDL_Texture* tileSet = IMG_LoadTexture(renderer, (RESOURCEPATH + filename).c_str());`. After that, we check if the tileSet is a null-pointer. With the thread we currently have, this seems to fail/succeed at a random rate.

Comment: @PimVerlangen Do you have any documentation on IMG_LoadTexture?

Comment: @PimVerlangen: I guess he meant the IMG_Load method from the SDL_image addon-library.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux Yeah I know but according to their docs `IMG_LoadTexture()` doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes, we are currently using `IMG_LoadTexture()`. We aren't entirely sure what the big difference is, but this seemed to work...